# Cost of using 10**9 over 1000000000?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, literals

In Python, are expressions like `10**9` made of literals also literals? What I am asking: **is there a cost to using expressions over less-meaningful but also less-computable literals** in code that is called very often and should be lightweight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more about readability and coding style. By writing something like `10**9` instead of `1000000000` or etc., you'll make your code shorter and more readable, thus its maintenance and improvement would be easier. If you want to use `10**9` multiple times in your code, as a more elegant way you'd better use it as a global variable at the top level of your module which is more elegant. Like:

```
MY_VARIABLE = 10**9
```

*Note* that even if you don't use a global variable name and use its numerical value through your code python will assume it's a constant value and won't recalculate it every time.

For example, as you can see in the following bytecode, python will load the constant value (which you defined in first part for `a`) for `c` and doesn't create a new object <sup>1</sup> for that:

```
>>> def test():
...    a = 10**9
...    b = 1000000000
...    c = 10**9
... 
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               4 (1000000000)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000000000)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               5 (1000000000)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

<sub>Note that python small integers are *singletons* and python will create only one copy of them (-5 to 256).</sub>

Comment: It's not more readable because it's shorter. It's more readable because you don't have to count zeroes.

Comment: @Rhymoid Indeed, and that was what I meant.

Comment: nit:  your b is 10**8

Answer (score 13):

There is no performance cost. Consider this:

```
import dis
def foo():
    x = 10**9
    y = 10**9

def bar():
    x = 1000000000
    y = 1000000000

dis.dis(foo)
dis.dis(bar)
```

yields

```
In [6]: dis.dis(foo)
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000000000)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  6           6 LOAD_CONST               4 (1000000000)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

In [8]: dis.dis(bar)
  9           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000000)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 10           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000000)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

So when Python compiles the code, it changes the `10**9` to `1000000000`. By the time the byte-code is run, there is no difference between using `10**9` or `1000000000`.

Comment: I think this "constant folding" is cpython implementation detail, though.

Answer (score 1):

After self reflection, I made some time measurements:

```
>>> import timeit

>>> def f():
...     return 10**9

>>> timeit.timeit(f)
0.13885498046875

>>> def f():
...     return 1000000000

>>> timeit.timeit(f)
0.13900208473205566
```

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a cost to using expressions, namely a performance cost due to [Python precomputing constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113609/why-does-Python-preemptively-hang-when-trying-to-calculate-a-very-large-number/34114371#34114371), but this cost is not likely to be noticeable in most cases, like in the case of `10**9`, more so with cases like `10**(10**10)`.

Comment: Good reference! So what you are saying is that computation is added, but one-time compile-time?